There are $10$ stations on circular track. A train has to stop at $3$ stations such that no two stations are consecutive. Find number of ways
There are $10$ stations on circular track. A train has to stop at $3$ stations such that no two stations are consecutive. In how many ways this can be done?
My Approach: Let train stop at $S_1, S_5, S_6$ there must be at least one gap between all three let there are $x$ gap between first station and second station, $y$ gap between second and third, $z$ gaps between $3$ and $1$ So $x+y+z=7$ where $x\geq 1, y\geq 1 z\geq 1$ so answer to this problems must be ${7-1\choose 3-1}=15$ but given anwer is $50$
Note: I took help of solution given by @gooddeeds in question Finding the number of consecutive objects?
Why this question can not be solved using my method?
Related Question: There are 10 stations on a circular path

Does the order of stops matter? Does the start station count?

what is meant by order of station?

Is $S_1, S_3, S_5$ same as $S_5, S_1, S_3$? If the order matters, $S_1, S_5, S_2$ is allowed, but not $S_1, S_2, S_5$

No we cannot arrrange stations

We shall use your $\Large{\binom{7-1}{3-1}}= 15$, but there are two crucial infirmities in it.

[1] The stations surely have identities, so multiplication by $10$ is needed to identify the first of each triple of stops.

[2] Due to the circular nature, each pattern of three stops will be counted  $3$ times


$$\text{Making these corrections, we get}
{\binom{7-1}{3-1}\times 10}/3 =50$$

Another Way
Looking clockwise make $3$ blocks of stops/non-stops $\boxed{\Large\bullet\Large\circ},$ treating each as one object.
This ensures that stops can never be adjacent,
There are now $3$ blocks plus $4$ "singles" $= 7$ objects, and the  blocks can be placed in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways,
but we are giving the blocks only $7$ starting points instead of $10$,
so we need to use a multiplication factor of $\dfrac{10}{7}$,
giving the answer $\dfrac{10}{7}\times\dbinom{7}{3}=50$


A circle does not have any beginning nor does it have any end. So we need to select any one station(say ($S_1$) as the starting point which can be done in $\binom{10}{1}=10$ ways. Then we select two stations ($S_2$) and ($S_3$) after putting $x,y,z$ stations between $S_1$ and $S_2$, between $S_2$ and $S_3$ and between $S_3$ and $S_1$ respectively.
Number of positive integral solutions to the equation $x+y+z=7$ is clearly $15$ as you have deduced.
So number of ways should be $\binom{10}{1}(15)=150$
But when we said that there are $\binom{10}{1}=10$ ways this means that the selected station could have been $S_2$ and $S_3$. So every combination is getting overcounted by a factor of $3$.
Thus the required number of ways $\frac{1}{3}\binom{10}{1}(15)=50$

Imagine $10$ stations in a line instead of a circle. We will count the number of station combinations restricted to the same condition. Let $y,z$ denote the gaps between the stations and $x,w$ denote the gaps between endpoint stations and $1$ and $10$ respectively:
$$1\underbrace{...}_\text{x}S_{1}\underbrace{...}_yS_{2}\underbrace{...}_\text{z}S_{3}\underbrace{...}_\text{w}10$$
Clearly, $x\geq0 \ , \ y\geq1 \ ,\ z\geq1, \ w\geq0$ and
$$x+y+z+w=7$$
$$\\$$
The number of solutions are $\dbinom{5+4-1}{4-1}=\dbinom{8}5=56$.
But we do not want the combinations where $S_{1}$ is $1$ and $S_{2}$ is $10$ simultaneously, as they would be consecutive on the circular path. There are $6$ such combinations. Hence our required answer is $$\boxed{56-6=50}$$

where $S_{1}$ $S_{2}$ $S_{3}$ are the stations at which the train stops

I want to know mistake in my method? I know other ways to solve this problem. I need to explain to some student mistake in this method

You have found the number of solutions to $x+y+z=7$ with the constraints, but this only gives you the number of unique gap combinations. You need to fix atleast one station to count each station combination.
For example, take the combinations $S_{1} , S_{3} , S_{5}$ and $S_{2} , S_{4} , S_{6}$. These are distinct combinations, but both have the same gaps $(x,y,z)=(1,1,5)$. You have counted both of these solutions (and all other $(1,1,5)$ gap combinations) only once.
This problem can easily be solved by fixing the first station, which is why we consider a linear track first. I have already uploaded the correct approach.
I hope this answers your query.
